# Being able to pull values of dictionary containing List<>

Tags: list, dictionary

Here is my dictionary datatype:

```
private Dictionary<String, List<PriceAndStandard>>
```

PriceAndStandard is a structure:

```
struct PriceAndStandard
{
  public double mePrice;
   public int? meStandard;
}
```

I want to be able to grab mePrice and meStandard for each item.

Error I am recieving

```
Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AspDotNetStorefront.showproduct.PriceAndStandard>
```

I would be able to grab the value if it were a basic key- string value pair with:

```
shaftModelDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

But because I have a list I really need to flatten out the data so it can be stored.

Working Code:

```
            foreach (string option in product.AvailableClubOptions.ShaftModel)
            {
                string shaftModelText = option;
                if (minPriceForShaftMaterial > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(option))
                {
                    List<PriceAndStandard> Paul = shaftModelDictionary.Keys.ToList();
                    double priceForShaftModel = shaftModelDictionary.[option];
                    double priceForSelectedShaftModel = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(shaftModel) ? shaftModelDictionary[shaftModel] : 0;
```

**Update:**
It seems like there is a problem with `option` since that is a string and  not compatible with the the values in my dictionary being lists.

**Update 2:**

```
foreach (string option in product.AvailableClubOptions.ShaftModel)
                    {
                        string shaftModelText = option;
                        if (minPriceForShaftMaterial > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(option))
                        {
                            double priceForShaftModel = shaftModelDictionary[option].mePrice;
                            double priceForSelectedShaftModel = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(shaftModel) ? shaftModelDictionary[shaftModel].mePrice : 0m;
                            double priceDelta = 0.0d;
                            double MinimumPrice = Convert.ToDouble(ltOurPrice.InnerText.Replace("$", ""));
```

'List' does not contain a definition for 'mePrice' and no extension method 'mePrice' accepting a first argument of type 'List'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
double priceForSelectedShaftModel = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(shaftModel) ? shaftModelDictionary[shaftModel].first().mePrice : 0d;
```

Edit:
My first answer was incorrect, sorry.  The values in your dictionary are Lists.  So when you retrieve a value (which is a list of PriceAndStandard objects), you need to either work with that list or find a specific PriceAndStandard object in the list to work with.  In the example I show I use the first() method to find a the first object in the list.  You may want to read up on LINQ and use the where() method or something similar.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish... are you sure you want the values in your dict to be Lists? There is nothing wrong with that except it is a bit unusual.  Perhaps you were thinking of this?:

```
private Dictionary<String, PriceAndStandard>
```

Also 0m is decimal, 0d is double.  My bad.

Comment: The first red swigely line is under double priceForShaftModel = shaftModelDictionary[option]

Comment: check update 2. mePrice has an underlined swigley in my IDE in both places in which they occur

Comment: Thanks for the followup. I think I am just being dumb. I shouldn't be using a list at all! PriceAndStandard may be the solve. Will let you know if it's not.

Comment: Overcomplicated things. KISS

Comment: Is your code working?  Please mark my answer if I helped you.  Thx.